# Cannot read property 'ordinal' of undefined for d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I've rewritten my program but the problem seems to be the ordinal scale of d3.js. I don't if because i'm using the v5 of d3. But I've read every article and samples of line chart but they are all using ordinal(). I don't know what's wrong with my code anymore.  I'm trying to create a line chart with the use of JSON data since sooner or later i'll connect it to my db that's why for now i'm just using dummy data to study it. But the ordinal error keeps popping out.

```
    var data = [{"symbol":"MSFT","date":"Day1","price":40},{"symbol":"MSFT","date":"Day2","price":23.18},{"symbol":"MSFT","date":"Day3","price":24.43},{"symbol":"MSFT","date":"Day4","price":25.49},{"symbol":"MSFT","date":"Day5","price":27.48},{"symbol":"MSFT","date":"Day6","price":29.27},{"symbol":"IBM","date":"Day1","price":100.52},{"symbol":"IBM","date":"Day2","price":92.11},{"symbol":"IBM","date":"Day3","price":106.11},{"symbol":"IBM","date":"Day4","price":99.95},{"symbol":"IBM","date":"Day5","price":96.31},{"symbol":"IBM","date":"Day6","price":98.33},{"symbol":"AAPL","date":"Day1","price":21},{"symbol":"AAPL","date":"Day2","price":26.19},{"symbol":"AAPL","date":"Day3","price":25.41},{"symbol":"AAPL","date":"Day4","price":30.47},{"symbol":"AAPL","date":"Day5","price":12.88},{"symbol":"AAPL","date":"Day6","price":9.78}]

// Set the dimensions of the canvas / graph
var margin = {top: 30, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50},
    width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 270 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// Parse the date / time
//var parseDate = d3.time.format("%b %Y").parse;

// Set the ranges
var x = d3.scale.ordinal().rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1);
var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);

// Define the axes
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x)
    .orient("bottom").ticks(5);

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y)
    .orient("left").ticks(5).innerTickSize(-width)
    .outerTickSize(0)
    .tickPadding(10);

// Define the line
var priceline = d3.svg.line()   
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.price); });

// Adds the svg canvas
var svg = d3.select("#lineChart")
    .append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
        .attr("transform", 
              "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

// Get the data
    // Scale the range of the data
    x.domain(data.map(function(d){ return d.date; }));
    y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.price; })]);

    // Nest the entries by symbol
    var dataNest = d3.nest()
        .key(function(d) {return d.symbol;})
        .entries(data);

    var color = d3.scale.category10();  // set the colour scale

    // Loop through each symbol / key
    dataNest.forEach(function(d) {

        svg.append("path")
            .attr("class", "line")
            .style("stroke", function() { // Add dynamically
                return d.color = color(d.key); })
            .attr("d", priceline(d.values));

    });

    // Add the X Axis
    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "x axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .call(xAxis);

    // Add the Y Axis
    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "y axis")
        .call(yAxis);

        d3.select(".y>path").remove();
```

Comment: If you are using version 5 a lot of code needs to be modified for from version 3 code. ```d3.scale.ordinal``` is now ```d3.scaleOrdinal```  https://iros.github.io/d3-v4-whats-new/#20 This is a link to the differences between V3 and V4 - a lot of which will be applicable to V5 as well